# How to select at least x rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have products ordered by price.
How to select all products costing less than 1 € otherwise continue search for select at least X products.

The SQL query has to return at least X rows at every time.

Comment: X Rows chosen *how*?

Comment: Can you not use `order by productcost limit x`?  Perhaps sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: did you tried anything? can you provide the query that you are trying now?

Comment: @sgeddes That will return at MOST x rows, not at LEAST x rows.

Comment: @Lamak, I would *guess* that OP would want the next least costly items. To your implied point, this is not at all clearly stated in the question.

Comment: @Lamak Yes I want to select a least 50 products that cost less than 1€ ordered by price. I f there are 100 products that cost less than 1€ I want these 100 products only. If there are 20 products that cost less than 1€ I want these 20 products and 30 others products whatever their price.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this purely in SQL, because the `LIMIT` clause can't take a computed value. Can you do it in a calling language like PHP?

Comment: If not, you'll need to write a stored procedure that creates dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Barmar dynamic sql possible without a stored procedure.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by "that creates dynamic SQL" ?

Comment: @NacimArrahmane Using a `PREPARE` statement. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @Mike how I can do this then ?

Comment: Get the count of products costing less than 1 €. If this is less than `x`, prepare a query that gets all products greater than 1 € with a limit of x-count, and union it with the query that returns all the products less than 1 €.

Comment: @NacimArrahmane `prepare stmt from "select * from table order by price desc limit ?";
set @cnt=(select if(count(1)>100,100,50) from table where price<1);
execute stmt using @cnt;`

Comment: @Mike why 100,100,50 ?

Comment: @NacimArrahmane it for example. if count()>100 then return 100 else return 50. Returned value = value for LIMIT

Comment: @Mike I have "bad arguments at EXECUTE statement" error

Comment: should work. tested. the number of parameters corresponds to the number of `?` in query ?

Answer (score -1):

Below is what it is in Microsoft SQL Server. I am not SUPER familiar with Mysql but the logic I would imagine stays somewhat the same. Instead of "TOP" you will have to use LIMIT in the bottom query.

```
DECLARE @Price as Money

SET @Price = 1

IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Product WHERE Price < @Price) > 50
SELECT
  ProductName
FROM
 Product
WHERE Price < @Price

ELSE
 SELECT TOP 50
  ProductName
 FROM Product
 ORDER BY Price
```

Rough MySQL conversion:

```
DECLARE PriceVar as DECIMAL(13,2)

SET PriceVar = 1

IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Product WHERE Price < PriceVar) > 50
SELECT
  ProductName
FROM
 Product
WHERE Price < PriceVar

ELSE
 SELECT 
  ProductName
 FROM Product
 ORDER BY Price LIMIT 50
```

Comment: You don't declare `@` variables in MySQL, and there's no `Money` datatype.

Comment: good to know...I made the changes. Definitely not an exact answer but I hope this at least gets onto the right track.

Answer (score -1):

Here is single select solution, hope it helps you.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (
        SELECT
            productname
        FROM
            Product
        WHERE Price < :Price
    )
    union all
    (   
        SELECT 
            productname
        FROM
            Product
        order by price desc limit :X
    )
) x limit :X
```

Based on number of executions and size of table there can be performace inpact but that can be solved by caching top products, second inner query, into different table.